# Linux Fedora 19 - iptables failed to start

Tags: linux, fedora, iptables

I've been trying to start the `iptables` firewall service, but it keeps failing. What's going wrong?

```
# systemctl status iptables.service
iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2013-10-26 11:01:54 CDT; 41s ago
 Process: 2114 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 26 11:01:54 localhost.localdomain iptables.init[2114]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 1 failed
Oct 26 11:01:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: iptables.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 26 11:01:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start IPv4 firewall with iptables.
Oct 26 11:01:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit iptables.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try (as root):

```
iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

If it fails, that should give you a more informative error.  If it works, something's perhaps wrong with the systemd service files.

Comment: It says:
iptables v1.4.18: no command specified

What can be wrong with systemd? it's a new Fedora installation..

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `iptables-restore` (corrected).

Comment: In my case, there was apparently syntax error in the automatically generated (!) config file. While fixing that, I found out that `systemctl start iptables` will automatically attempt to load `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, so creating a copy of that files and fixing that copy won't help; rather create a backup of that file and then modify the original file.